# Why pass the name of object in creating namedtuple subclass?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray, namedtuple

I know this is the format of creating `namedtuple` p:

```
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
p = Point(11, y=22)
```

Why do we pass the name of the **object**, here `Point` as one of the arguments of `namedtuple`. If `Point` here is the new subclass of tuple with named field, won't its caller be automatically passed as the **first argument**? Why can't `namedtuple` be called/initiated similar to `numpy.array`

```
import numpy
l = numpy.array([1, 2, 3]) # so simple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `typing.NamedTuple` to avoid the duplicate name declaration.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: float
    y: float
```

---

The `collections.namedtuple` is not a type, it is a type factory;
each `namedtuple` constitutes a separate type. For example, a `namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])` and `namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y', 'z'])` are separate types. Python defaults to [nominal typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), and relies on the type name to report and [store types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). As such, a type like `namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])` should know its name, and thus needs it passed in.

In contrast, `numpy.array` already is a type, with a known name `array`. `numpy.array([1, 2, 3])` creates an *instance* of the `array`, just like `Point(1, 2)` creates an *instance* of the namedtuple `Point`.

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thanks for the answer.